# How to access primefaces' previous version showcase

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I was using primefaces 5 for an app, and now I need to do some modifications, but in the showcase [page](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase) I can only access version 6, which is not compatible with my version. every time I tested a component I get  this error :
`Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name:` 

Can anyone help ??
PS: I cannot migrate to version 6

**EDIT**
version of primefaces that I use is 5

**Solution**
for those who face the same problem here is the [link](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/releases/) to download any showcase version.
download it and follow the read me .

Comment: There 100% is a value after 'name:'. Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrimeFaces did not keep track (tag) of versions of the showcase before the [5.0 release](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/tree/5_0). The earliest commits in GitHub are of April 2014 and version 4 was released in October 2013.

Before that, Googlecode was used and they migrated the code AND history from 'svn' to github. That code is in https://github.com/svn2github/primefaces-showcase, where you can easily go back to October 2nd 2013 where the 4.0(-SNAPSHOT) was updated to 4.1(-SNAPSHOT).

[Browsing the repository](https://github.com/svn2github/primefaces-showcase/tree/3e242755cccfb325a7a91df5a523da9b97486c99) for that version (or [downloading](https://github.com/svn2github/primefaces-showcase/archive/3e242755cccfb325a7a91df5a523da9b97486c99.zip) it!) is possible. Might be that you need to go 1 commit back but be creative... it is still all there.

Comment: thank you for responding, but I think that this is version 4, and even with this version, and even in  this version there are some errors when running clean install

Comment: You 'ask' about version 4, so I fail to see the problem (the showcase not compiling is beyond the scope of this Q/A)

Comment: you were right, I made a mistack, I was looking for version 5,

Comment: concerning the problems, I don't see another way to access the showcase other than download the project, build it, and deploy it on a server in order to access showcase

Comment: Correct, if you expected anything else, you should have mentioned that.

Comment: I find the solution

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for it too, and I've found it here:

https://pseudohub.de/primefaces-5.3-showcase

https://primefaces.zeef.com    (see Primefaces showcases section)